# Bash script to create network command template

Tags: bash, networking

My point is to create a file containing network command starting from a text file that contains some IP. For example:

File with IPs:

```
1.1.1.1,
2.2.2.2,
3.3.3.3,
......
```

From this list I need to create a new file that contains 2 types of commands, like these:

```
set security zones security-zone 1 address-book address H-1.1.1.1 1.1.1.1/32 - 
set security zones security-zone 1 address-book address-set GROUP address H-1.1.1.1
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Is the _File with IPs_ a one-line, comma-separated list?

Comment: Please format that so it can be readable.

Comment: @Armali no there isn't a comma, is one IP one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk.

The `printf` version

```
cat tst.awk
```

Output

```
{ 
  printf "set security zones security-zone 1 address-book address H-%s %s/32 -\nset security zones security-zone 1 address-book address-set GROUP address H-%s\n", $0, $0, $0
}
```

The `print` version.

```
{
  message = "set security zones security-zone 1 address-book address"
  print message, "H-" $0, $0 "/32", "-"
  print message "-set", "GROUP", "address", "H-" $0
}
```

The file

```
cat file.txt
```

Output

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

Run

```
awk -f tst.awk file.txt > out.txt
```

Check the out.txt

```
cat out.txt
```

Output

```
    set security zones security-zone 1 address-book address H-1.1.1.1 1.1.1.1/32 -
    set security zones security-zone 1 address-book address-set GROUP address H-1.1.1.1
    set security zones security-zone 1 address-book address H-2.2.2.2 2.2.2.2/32 -
    set security zones security-zone 1 address-book address-set GROUP address H-2.2.2.2
    set security zones security-zone 1 address-book address H-3.3.3.3 3.3.3.3/32 -
    set security zones security-zone 1 address-book address-set GROUP address H-3.3.3.3
```

Comment: I tried both solutions and works really well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop with appropriate redirections would do:

```
while read IP
do  echo set security zones security-zone 1 address-book address H-$IP $IP/32 -
    echo set security zones security-zone 1 address-book address-set GROUP address H-$IP
done <File >new_file
```